# What nails to use for PT wood?

Tags: nails, pressure-treated, corrosion

I'm re-framing my first floor and using PT wood everywhere where there is a possibility of area being flooded.

PT wood is your [typical 2x4(s) from Home Depot MCA](http://www.homedepot.com/p/WeatherShield-2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-1-Southern-Pine-Pressure-Treated-Lumber-254258/202088114) - micronized copper azole chemicals.

I guess I've never realized that PT lumber is corrosive. Which collated nails should I use in my framing gun? Stainless?

Comment: Are you allowed to use PT lumber for indoors framing in your area?? I doubt it.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey yeah. the problem was afaik only CCA PT wood which was arsenic. It was phased out and replaced with different type PT chemical which is allowed indoors. In fact - required for anything touching concrete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In general, the codes require fasteners to be of hot-dipped, zinc-coated galvanized steel in accordance with ASTM A153, type 304 or 316 stainless steel, silicon bronze or copper.  [[source]](http://www.southernpine.com/fasteners-connectors/)

FWIW, everything you ever wanted to know about pressure treated wood [here](http://www.strongtie.com/products/product-use-information/corrosion-information/pressure-treated-wood-faq).

Answer (score 3):

Stainless is the most reliable way to go, though [hot-dipped galvanized is also an option](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/4-tips-for-using-galvanized-nails-with-pressure-treated-wood#b). It wasn't an issue until CCA was phased out a few years back.

Comment: To spoil the linked article: they have to be *hot-dipped* galvanized. Electroplated-galvanized nails will corrode in pressure-treated wood.

Comment: To clarify further, they all corrode. It's a matter of coating thickness and longevity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds cliche, but your best bet is to visit a local lumber yard. Not only will they likely have what you need to go with the lumber, but more often than not, if it's a decent sized pro yard, they will have #1 grade cheaper than HD or Lowe's #2.